# Static Property Doesn't Stay Set

Tags: php, static

I have a class, That accesses static variables, and the method `stuff_field` puts them into a `tplItms::$replacements` array.

```
<?php
require_once "../src/acesse.inc.php";
require_once "../src/members/memberPage.inc.php";
$page_class = (isset($_SESSION['acesse_member']) && $_SESSION['acesse_member']) ? "memberPage" : "acessePage";
$p = new $page_class('{lang[Welcome-VServices]}', 'shell.tpl');
$t = new tpl('home_shell.tpl');

$top = ($page_class == 'memberPage') ? '' : tpl::translateTpl('hometop');
$t->stuff_field('php', 'HomeTop', $top);
$t->stuff_field('php', 'Home', tpl::translateTpl('home'));
$p->tpl->stuff_field('php', 'Content', $t->get_markup());

if (false) {    // servicebox displayer code, for posterity
    $p = new $page_class('{lang[Welcome-VServices]}', 'shell.tpl');
    $db = new vservdb();
    $db->query("SELECT title AS ServiceName, primary_url AS ServiceURL FROM vservices WHERE display=1 ORDER BY listing_priority DESC, title");
    $t = new tpl('servicebox.tpl');
    while($r = $db->nextrow()) {
        $t_clone = clone $t;
        $page = $r['ServiceName']=="V-Newswire" ? '/index.php' : '';
        $r['ServiceURL'] = $r['ServiceURL'] .$page.'?lang='.$_SESSION['lang'];
        $t_clone->stuff_php($r);    
        $markup .= $t_clone->get_markup();
    }
    $p->tpl->stuff_php('Content', "<div class=\"centered\">$markup</div>");
}

print_r(tplItms::$replacements);
echo $p->display();
```

When I do the `print_r()` as in the example above, all the expected items are in the array. But if I move the `print_r()` into the `display()` method, all the items are gone, why?

Here is the display method:

```
public function display($template, $field = null, $value = null, $value2 = null, $end = false){
    print_r(tplItms::$replacements);
    if(empty($template))
        return false;
    $ad = new tpl($template, null, $end);
    if($field)
        $ad->stuff_field($field, $value, $value2);
    $ad->setup();
    return $ad->get_markup();
}
```

If it helps, here is the `tplItms` class:

```
class tplItms{
    public static $replacements = array();
}
```

Why are they gone? What can I do so they are not gone? I can't really modify the `display()` parameters because there are 1,000's of pages that use this `display()` method

Comment: Do you have error handling / display enabled? You should at least get a warning as you are calling your method without the (required...) `$template` parameter.

Comment: I didn't originally write this code, and the page works without errors (display errors is on). I am not sure why either...

Comment: Are all these classes within the same php file ? If not, how do you handle the inclusions : require/require_once/other ?

Comment: They are handled above, as I didn't display the whole file.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me... but your code might be more complex than it looks like. Maybe your code is using namespaces or you have more than one display method in your class (overloading) because you are calling the display method without any parameters but it looks like it needs at least $template...

Comment: @qxxx, So, it looks like I was looking at the wrong function, I needed to look at a `display()` function that calls the `display()` function above. It fixed my issue!